# Custom middleware mapped to route to accept POST method

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5

I need a route that accepts POST request with a custom middleware.
I implement it but not accepts POST request and return ERROR 405.
How to configure the Middleware to accepts POST requests?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to check if the request is Post in middleware?If so you can do like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Method == "POST")
                {
                    //do sth
                }
                else {
                    //do sth
                }
                await next();
            });

            ...........

         }
```